# Is it ok to use tutorials for zf1 in order to learn zf2 or will I run into compatibility issues?

Tags: zend-framework2

I have had some difficulty in finding resources (as in actual tutorials) for working with zf2. The Zend official site is ok but not brilliant. I learn better by example and the getting started album tutorial only really covers a small amount. I have found loads of stuff for ZF1.

It is easy to find tutorials for zf1 with a search engine but simply putting "Zend framework 2" will obviously just give you all the results of Zend Framework 1 with any other specific "2" contained in the articles, for example, "chapter 2" or "2 comments".

My main question is therefore:

Is it ok to just follow the tutorials for the older framework? Specifically, I am thinking of the likes of "Surviving the deep end" and similar books. Will these guides lead to confusion when trying to apply them to zf2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're better of searching for specific ZF2 Stuff. While the ZF1 Stuff will *sometimes* be helpful in order to get to know where to look for specific features, most of the time it will not be all that helpful at all. The *"easy"* stuff wil be kinda easy to find for ZF2, too, and the In-Depth-Stuff needed for ZF1 will not be the same inside the ZF2-Core.

There's couple of blogs out there that are really helpful. I can only suggest to take a look at the contributor-list of the GitHub_Repository and look for the blog of those guys. I'd argue that for all small applications there's tutorials to be found on those websites. Just to name a few:

- [Michael Gallego aka Bakura](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/)
- [Rob Allen aka Akrabat](http://akrabat.com/)
- [Evan Coury aka EvanDotPro](http://blog.evan.pro/)
- [Matthew Weier O'Phinney](http://mwop.net/)
- [Ben Scholzen aka DASRPRID](http://www.dasprids.de/)
- [Charles Spraggs aka SpiffyJr](http://www.spiffyjr.me/)
- [Jurian Sluiman](http://juriansluiman.nl/en/)
- [Adam Lundrigan](http://adam.lundrigan.ca/)
- [Manuel Stosic aka Sam](http://samminds.com)
- [Abdhul Ikhsan aka Samsonasik](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/)

And I'm sure there's a couple of more higher quality blogs out there that i simply do not know of :)

Comment: I will give those a look through. I have been to the site that is the last on your list but I found that his login system was kind of incomplete and could not get it to work. I may end up just sifting through the zf2 reference and experiment with different things.